# How do I simulate the global variable in Node's vm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I'm trying to use [node.js's vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module for an automated test I'm writing, as far as I can tell, it doesn't build an environment with the `global` variable:

```
$ node -p 'const vm = require("node:vm"); const context = {}; vm.runInNewContext("global.foo=5;", context); console.log(context);'
evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
global.foo=5;
^

ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

It does seem to come with `globalThis`, though:

```
$ node -p 'const vm = require("node:vm"); const context = {}; vm.runInNewContext("globalThis.foo=5;", context); console.log(context);'
{ foo: 5 }
undefined
```

I'm not sure why or even how it's missing `global`, but how do I create a vm context with it?

Note: I'm going to answer my question but I'm not confident it's a good solution. Let me know if it can be improved.

Comment: "*I'm not sure why or even how it's missing global*" - well [`globalThis` is part of the language](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-globalthis) whereas [`global` is not](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global)

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure if I follow. Are you sharing this as a *hypothesis* for why it *might* be missing `global`, or is there more behind to it than that?

Comment: Not a conjecture, more a conclusion. The `vm` docs say "*Inside such scripts, the `contextObject` will be the global object, retaining all of its existing properties but also having the built-in objects and functions any standard global object has.*" It refers to the standard ECMAScript globals only. The nodejs globals (like `global`, `console` or `process`) are not made available by default

Comment: @Bergi Oh. Okay now I understand and agree with your conclusion, but I'm not completely sure how to get to it on my own. Does the "standard" in "standard global object" imply "ECMAScript standard"?

Comment: There is no other standard I'm aware of :-) Also the docs author linked "global object" to https://es5.github.io/#x15.1, so it surely is what they meant.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the information! I learned a lot from your last comment; I was under the assumption that "node," "npm," and "browsers," all conformed to supersets of the ECMAScript standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `global` in `context` as a reference to itself:

```
$ node -p 'const vm = require("node:vm"); const context = {}; context.global = context; vm.runInNewContext("global.foo=5;", context); console.log(context);'
<ref *1> { global: [Circular *1], foo: 5 }
undefined
```

This more elaborate example shows that `globalThis === global` within the context:

```
$ node -p 'const vm = require("node:vm"); const context = { console }; context.global = context; vm.runInNewContext("global.foo=5; console.log(\"vm.runInNewContext\", globalThis.foo)", context); console.log("outside", context); console.log("outside foo", context.foo);'
vm.runInNewContext 5
outside <ref *1> {
  console: Object [console] {
    log: [Function: log],
    warn: [Function: warn],
    dir: [Function: dir],
    time: [Function: time],
    timeEnd: [Function: timeEnd],
    timeLog: [Function: timeLog],
    trace: [Function: trace],
    assert: [Function: assert],
    clear: [Function: clear],
    count: [Function: count],
    countReset: [Function: countReset],
    group: [Function: group],
    groupEnd: [Function: groupEnd],
    table: [Function: table],
    debug: [Function: debug],
    info: [Function: info],
    dirxml: [Function: dirxml],
    error: [Function: error],
    groupCollapsed: [Function: groupCollapsed],
    Console: [Function: Console],
    profile: [Function: profile],
    profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
    timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp],
    context: [Function: context],
    createTask: [Function: createTask]
  },
  global: [Circular *1],
  foo: 5
}
outside foo 5
undefined
```